# How to Fully Backup and Restore gpg Keys, Signatures and Settings

Tags: 20.04, backup, gnupg, restore

My **gpg backup process** so far is:

```
$ gpg --export-ownertrust > PATH/TO/BACKUP/ownertrust.txt
$ cp -u ~/.gpgrc PATH/TO/BACKUP/
$ cp -u ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf PATH/TO/BACKUP/
$ gpg --export-secret-keys --armor
copy and paste/print/save output to your choice of secure place (ideally offline and offsite)
```

My **gpg restore process** so far is:

```
$ gpg --list-keys # make sure gpg is installed and initiated (install if necessary)
$ rm ~/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg
Copy private key to temporary file if not in file format
$ gpg --import TEMPFILE.asc # substitute TEMPFILE with your sig/asc filename
$ gpg --import-ownertrust PATH/TO/BACKUP/ownertrust.txt
```

This gets me up and running again, but none of the 3rd party (e.g. skype, ubuntu, archlinux, etc...) public keys or signatures that I had before are restored.

**How** do I **modify** my **backup and restore processes** to **capture** these **3rd party keys** and **signatures**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This gets me up and running again, but none of the 3rd party (e.g. skype, ubuntu, archlinux, etc...) public keys or signatures that I had before are restored.

That is because you only exported your own keys (`--export-secret-keys`). To export all public keys you must use the `--export` command.

> How do I modify my backup and restore processes to capture these 3rd party keys and signatures?

Add `--export` (to export your public keyring and exportable signatures) with the option `--export-options backup` (to include all local signatures) to your **gpg export process**:

```
$ gpg --export-options backup -o PATH/TO/BACKUP/keyring.gpg --export
```

Then add the following to your **gpg restore process**:

```
$ gpg --import-options restore --import PATH/TO/BACKUP/keyring.gpg
```